# How to write custom handlers in Vert.x3?

Tags: javascript, vert.x

I am new to Vert.x (using version 3.2.1). AFAIK, We can create custom handlers using Java like this:

```
public class MyHandler implements Handler<RoutingContext>{
   @Override
   public void handle(RoutingContext context) {

   }
   ...
}
```

Is there any way to write the same using Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript you use the JS closure notation e.g.:

```
function (ctx) { ... }
```

A full hello word example:

```
var Router = require("vertx-web-js/router");

var router = Router.router(vertx);

router.route().handler(function (routingContext) {
  routingContext.response().putHeader("content-type", "text/html").end("Hello World!");
});
```

vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router.accept).listen(8080);

Comment: Ok, but how can I define the same (JS closure notation) in a separate JS file, and pass to calling function?

Comment: you can require a external file with `var other = require('other_js_file');` and then reference it from the exports, so if your exports are like: `module.exports = { fn : function (ctx) { ctx.response().end('Hello'); }}}` then after you require you can always do: `router.route().handler(other.fn)`